# How can Last_Execution_time be before Creation_time?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, sp-healthparser, sys.dm-exec-query-stats

sp_HealthParser (made by Erik Darling) crashed on me, because Last_Execution_time was way before Creation_time. 
How is that possible?

The columns :
**Last_execution_time** in sys.dm_exec_query_stats should, in my book, be on or after **Creation_time** (from the same sys.dm_exec_query_stats)?

The query fails at

```
datediff
(
   SECOND,
   deqs.creation_time,
   deqs.last_execution_time
) , 0)
```

which I've fixed by adding a case statement like this:

```
case when deqs.creation_time < deqs.last_execution_time then datediff
(
   SECOND,
   deqs.creation_time,
   deqs.last_execution_time
) else 0 end
```

I now get 1106 rows with last_execution_time equal to **1900-01-01 00:00:00.000**, all with plan_generation_num=1 and execution_count=1

Comment: I suggest email Erik directly or raising a GitHub issue about it. Give a clear example of the problem. He'll likely address it.

Comment: from an extremely brief glance at the code it looks like these are pulled directly from the corresponding columns in `sys.dm_exec_query_stats`

Comment: @DanCo I can certainly fix it in my code, but that doesn’t explain why data with those values ends up in the DMV (which I would be interested to learn about).

Comment: @martin; yes, I should have written that. I'll update the question.

Comment: @ErikDarling I'm also curious. If the db/code "crashed", how was OP able to identify an issue with the `last_execution_time` being behind the `creation_time`? The original question seems to point to your code. OP needs to provide an error message or a screenshot for clarity. I believe your code isn't the issue here (and it shouldn't be included in the question/tag). If there's a potential bug in `sys.dm_exec_query_stats`, it would be best to escalate this to Microsoft. They would likely require a detailed repo of the issue. Without these specifics, we're limited in how we can help OP further.

Comment: @DanCo; I've suggested a fix to Erik, that will avoid the crash if the Last_execution_time is before Creation_time. But the real question is really; how is this possible?

Comment: @HenrikStaunPoulsen can you update your question with a screenshot of the problem data, with as much detail as you can reasonably show?